# How do I change the font type of the text in a Matplotlib table?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I have a sample table made in matplotlib below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

collabel=("col 1", "col 2", "col 3")
new_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

the_table = plt.table(cellText=new_data,colLabels=collabel,loc='center')
plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

I would just simply like to change the font type of the text shown in the tables (i.e. Arial, Courier, etc). I couldn't find a font property in the table() method, should I be trying to grab text items within the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the font family in `plt.rcParams` before you plot the table:

```py
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Serif'
the_table = plt.table(cellText=new_data, colLabels=collabel, loc='center')
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a specific _fontname_?

Answer (score 0):

As tdy just mentionned:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

collabel = ("col 1", "col 2", "col 3")
new_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Serif'
the_table = plt.table(cellText=new_data, colLabels=collabel, loc='center')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

And you can find the documentation just here : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html?highlight=rc%20params#matplotlib.rc

Comment: How is this answer any different from tdy's?

Comment: Just added the doc link, comment under his response would have been better ? :/

Comment: Yes that would have been better.

Comment: Not enough reputation (need 50)... :/
But thank you :)